# Why can I create Global objects as non Admin?

Tags: c#, windows, security

The Create Global Objects privilege
[image]

grants access to Administrators, Service, Local and Network service.
Based on that when I create a local user with no Admin rights

[image]

and I start a shell via

```
runas /user:testuser cmd.exe
```

and then start my MutexTest application I should get an Access Denied Exception (System.UnauthorizedAccessException).
But this succeeds.

[image]

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace MutexTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rule = new MutexAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
            var mutexSecurity = new MutexSecurity();
            mutexSecurity.AddAccessRule(rule);
            
            var mutex = new Mutex(false, $"Global\\TestlollMutex{new Random().Next()}", out bool createdNew);
            if(createdNew)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Allowing everyone access to mutex");
                mutex.SetAccessControl(mutexSecurity);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for work... Press Enter to exit.");

            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

The question is why can I create that global object although I should not be able to do so?
What am I missing? When I look with SystemInformer I do not see the privilege enabled:

[image]

**Update 1**

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/kernel-object-namespaces

> The creation of a file-mapping object in the global namespace, by
> using CreateFileMapping, from a session other than session zero is a
> privileged operation. Because of this, an application running in an
> arbitrary Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server session
> must have SeCreateGlobalPrivilege enabled in order to create a
> file-mapping object in the global namespace successfully. The
> privilege check is limited to the creation of file-mapping objects,
> and does not apply to opening existing ones. For example, if a service
> or the system creates a file-mapping object, any process running in
> any session can access that file-mapping object provided that the user
> has the necessary access.

do I not need this privilege for Mutexes if I reverse the meaning of the text and assume this privilege is only meant for global file mapping objects? But I have also the opposite case where the creation of global mutexes fail. Which security setting is then responsible for this if it is not this privilege?

**Update 1 end**
**Update 2**
With ETW Syscall Tracing I could find that ntdll.dll!NtOpenDirectoryObject fails with NTSTATUS 0xC0000022 = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. What is even more interesting that when I modify my MutexTester to retry the operation in case of an exception it stops and some point in time. So this has nothing to do with my granted security but somehow the environment where it executes has changed.

[image]
When I enable more ETW providers I find that Session 1 is created quite quickly and my process is started as Administrative user but keeps getting exceptions until I logon interactively. Only then the exceptions will go away. There is a tight correlation between my interactive logon and the suddenly working MutexTester. The process has not crashed it is still alive happily it just does not get exceptions anymore. Is this behavior expected?

[image]

The exception was

```
Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.Threading.Mutex+MutexTryCodeHelper.MutexTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexWithGuaranteedCleanup(Boolean, System.String, Boolean ByRef, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)
   at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean, System.String, Boolean ByRef, System.Security.AccessControl.MutexSecurity)
```

**Update 2 End**

Comment: I don't think 'Global' needs restricted access, it just means that it's available across every session.

Comment: @Neil: I have added the comment for kernel namespaces which explicitly mention file mapping objects. But I am not sure if this relates only to file mapping objects or mutexes as well. I have the case that the same user running under a different session is not able to create global mutexes. I fail to understand how this is possible because I found no tool which would show me a security related setting (Logon Token) which could explain this.

Comment: Yeah, I found that page too, still doesn't mention that you need any special privileges to create a global named kernel object.

Comment: The privilege controls only file mapping objects. Other types of objects (such as mutexes) are not subject to SeCreateGlobalPrivilege. (Though they may be subject to other restrictions. Just not SeCreateGlobalPrivilege.)

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks for the clarification. So the privileges of the primary or linked token are not responsible for this. But then the question remains what other part of the Primary or Linked token prevents me in specific cases from creating mutexes in the Global kernel namespace. I am at a loss which security setting is responsible for this.

Comment: You showed the code that successfully created a global mutex. You did not show the code that fails to create a global mutex. One case where you cannot do it is if there is already a non-mutex object with the same name.

Comment: @RaymondChen: This code fails If it is executed under the same user account in the same session. I have code which does a LogonUser to create a new session but sometimes global Mutex creation fails for unknown reasons when the above code runs in that session. Are there differencs between interaktive/first sessions?

Comment: Another case where you cannot create a global mutex is if the process is at low integrity. And if course it can fail if the mutex already exists and its permissions don't grant you access.

Comment: @RaymoundChen: The process has Medium Integrity and I give everyone access and I use a random number (for testing) to ensure it cannot already exist. Still I get sometimes an UnauthorizedAccessException which is a mystery for me because with the usual tools I cannot see any difference from the Token object and my second process which runs in the same session, same user, but this time it works. Perhaps I can strip rights from the token object during LogonUser? But where would I see that?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I have added more details when this is happening. The error goes away when I log in interactively and my still running process suddenly can create the mutex. That is kind of unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that during system startup my starter service did start the process as a regular user. It looks like Windows is setting for Global objects access rights only after one user did log in interactively.

If you try to create global objects from an otherwise Admin user which is running under Medium or higher integrity you will get access denied until the first interactive user did log in.